# Yeoman generator.fs.copyTpl - How to output literal '<%'

Tags: yeoman, yeoman-generator

I'm working on my first Yeoman generator and need to output some literal ejs tags for later processing. I'm able to achieve this by escaping the tag with an additional '%' per the ejs docs (http://ejs.co/). For example:

```
<%% myModule %>
```

I can process this without issue using the deprecated *generator.template()*, and the destination file contains the expected output:

```
<% myModule %>
```

However, when I attempt to use *generator.fs.copyTpl()* to process the same file, I get the following synthax error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token %
```

Do I need to explicitly pass an escape character in the ejs options object? Is there something else I'm missing?

Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: You need yeoman-generator ^0.20.0 in your package.json

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `<%%` just works with ejs and yeoman-generator.

My guess is that you're not using the latest version of `yeoman-generator`.

Run this in your generator project:

`npm install --save yeoman-generator@LATEST`

Also, there's a useful tool called [david](https://david-dm.org/) to detect outdated dependencies.

```
npm -g install david
# Then in your project folder
david
```

Comment: Thanks, Simon! You're correct, I was on 0.19.0 of yeoman-generator. Updated and everything works as expected. Also, thanks for the heads up on david - great tool!